# How to categorize tweets(supportive vs. unsupportive) to predict elections results

Tags: python, twitter, nlp, prediction, sentiment-analysis

**The idea**

I am collecting tweets talking about the three major candidates for the US presidency in November. After collecting the tweets from different states, I will score these tweets, and then analyze each candidate's followers/supporters on various aspects.

**The problem**

I am sure what method I should use to classify the tweets in order to produce reasonable outcomes. More precisely, I don't know how to tell if a tweet is supporting or opposing a specific candidate.

**What I tried**

I tried to use a library called **textblob**. Given a tweet, it returns a tuple of the form Sentiment(polarity, subjectivity). Polarity is a float which lies in the range of [-1,1] where 1 means positive statement and -1 means a negative statement. This method does not return reasonable results at all when applied. For example, given a tweet like **"Donald Trump is horrible! I still support him tho."**, it returns a polarity of **-1.0** (negative), which does not make any sense at all.

**Further Research**

I looked for more examples and found [this](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/twitter-sentiment-analysis-for-the-2019-election-8f7d52af1887). In that example, the author uses a mood vocabulary (from the internet) and later assigns a mood to each tweet. I am planning to take a close look at that article and apply the method used there.

**My questions**

- What is a proper way to categorize those tweets? Should I consider the one I mentioned in the further research section?
- What if a tweet contains both names? something like "Trump will beat Biden". How something like this is going to be scored using a specific method?

Comment: this sounds more like a project for a thesis than a question for stack overflow

Comment: This is a very broad, open-ended question, and an active area of research. Sentiment analysis of short texts (tweets) is extremely difficult to do reliably due to all the nuances of grammar and intent, sarcasm etc. Not something that can really be answered on SO, I think.

Answer (score 0):

[Sentiment Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis) is a topic of NLP (Natural language processing). What you are wondering is about NLP which is one of many interesting branches of machine learning.

Your approach to weigh out the polarity of a tweet is correct. Since you have 3 different candidates aka. labels, this is a more interesting problem.

I would store a sentiment array of length 3 for each tweet in order to calculate weights for each candidate. For example; a tweet like "A is bad. B will do much better! But also C might too?" might produce [-1, 0.8, 0.4].

To do that, you need a [corpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus). The corpus aka your dataset should contain tweets and labels for each tweet so that your machine learning model can learn from the tweets.

There are many ways to build a machine learning model and train it with your dataset. That is a topic of data science. Data scientists try to improve some performance indicators in order to improve their model.

The simpliest would be something like, parse out all words out of tweet, increment their values in a hash map with labels and normalize. Now you have a hash map containing the sentiment value for each word.

But in reality, this would not work out well as outliers and lack of dataset would affect your result. Therefore, you need to look at your data, problem and choose the right machine learning model. Look at this [article](http://[Sentiment%20Analysis][1]%20is%20a%20topic%20of%20NLP%20(Natural%20language%20processing).%20What%20you%20are%20wondering%20is%20about%20NLP%20which%20is%20one%20of%20many%20interesting%20branches%20of%20machine%20learning.%20%20Your%20approach%20to%20weigh%20out%20the%20polarity%20of%20a%20tweet%20is%20correct.%20Since%20you%20have%203%20different%20candidates%20aka.%20labels,%20this%20is%20a%20more%20interesting%20problem.%20%20%20I%20would%20store%20a%20sentiment%20array%20of%20length%203%20for%20each%20tweet%20in%20order%20to%20calculate%20weights%20for%20each%20candidate.%20For%20example;%20a%20tweet%20like%20%22A%20is%20bad.%20B%20will%20do%20much%20better!%20But%20also%20C%20might%20too?%22%20might%20produce%20[-1,%200.8,%200.4].%20%20To%20do%20that,%20you%20need%20a%20[corpus][2].%20The%20corpus%20aka%20your%20dataset%20should%20contain%20tweets%20and%20labels%20for%20each%20tweet%20so%20that%20your%20machine%20learning%20model%20can%20learn%20from%20the%20tweets.%20%20There%20are%20many%20ways%20to%20build%20a%20machine%20learning%20model%20and%20train%20it%20with%20your%20dataset.%20That%20is%20a%20topic%20of%20data%20science.%20Data%20scientists%20try%20to%20improve%20some%20performance%20indicators%20in%20order%20to%20improve%20their%20model.%20%20%20The%20simpliest%20would%20be%20something%20like,%20parse%20out%20all%20words%20out%20of%20tweet,%20increment%20their%20values%20in%20a%20hash%20map%20with%20labels%20and%20normalize.%20Now%20you%20have%20a%20hash%20map%20containing%20the%20sentiment%20value%20for%20each%20word.%20%20%20But%20in%20reality,%20this%20would%20not%20work%20out%20well%20as%20outliers%20and%20lack%20of%20dataset%20would%20affect%20your%20result.%20Therefore,%20you%20need%20to%20look%20at%20your%20data,%20problem%20and%20choose%20the%20right%20machine%20learning%20model.%20Look%20at%20this%20[article][3]%20to%20build%20a%20Sentiment%20Classifier.%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis%20%20%20[2]:%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus%20%20%20[3]:%20https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-sentiment-classifier-using-scikit-learn-54c8e7c5d2f0) to learn more about building a sentiment classifier.